# C# - Extending a EventSource manifest with additional events

Tags: c#, .net, events, logging, etw

Is it possible to register multiple manifests under the same event source name with exclusive event ids, and have the resulting event provider be able to consume all the supplied events from more than one manifest?

For example if I have two projects (two .man files and two .dll files that have exclusive event Id's that map to the same event provider (by name and GUID)) and do:

> wevutil im "path to 1st .man file"

followed by

> wevtutil im "path to 2nd .man file"

I get the message back:

> ****Warning Publisher {GUID} is already installed on the system. **Only new values will be added**. If you want to update previous settings, uninstall the manifest first.

So what are the actual "values" that get updated? If I execute now

> wevtutil gp "path to 2nd .man file"

I thought it would return the provider name with the mapped events from both .dlls. However it only seems to be mapping the latter manifest and discarding the one we install first. Is there a way we can "extend" a manifest?

Comment: This is not possible. why do you want to do this?

Comment: Multiple projects that could be put under the same "Product" umbrella. Having a uniform log rather than separate individual logs is the goal.

Comment: I see eventsource 4.6 supports dynamic events, but they are not playing well for a event provider already registered with a manifest. While I see dynamic events do not support an id and message attributes with them, they still are being sent to the event log with a event id of a different registered event for that provider

Comment: use 1 eventsource class with its events per project and don't try what you want to do